# Google Analytics for third-party embedded widget

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

I've been able to test this to a certain extent within our application, however I'm still testing the waters with google analytics to see if it is the best choice for app analytics; for externally embedded javascript.

I'm able to fire custom events, and custom page views.  However I'd like to see all online users across all sites that have the widget embedded on.  It currently shows online users, but it uses a relative URL path, instead of the domain or full path.

The type of data points I'm hoping to gather are specific interactions the user makes with the application, as well as live statistics which can be drilled down to the publisher of the embed.

Has anyone had experience using google analytics for third party embeds? or is there another service out there that is better suited for app analytics of this nature?

Comment: I've found some documentation regarding showing domains and allowing cross domain tracking. (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#keyComponents)  However I'm still curious to hear some other thoughts on this matter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Analytics for 3rd party JavaScript widgets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328664/analytics-for-3rd-party-javascript-widgets)